# Django Admin: How can I override a model verbose_name?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models (Country and State) and I've made only one ModelAdmin for Country with an TabularInline for State.

```
class StateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = State

class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['name']}),
    ]
    inlines = [StateInline]

admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

How can I override the `verbose_name` Meta property of Country model? I want to rename the form in menu to "Countries / States", instead of only "Countries"?

Answer (score 14):

using [Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name)

in your model:

```
from django.utils.tranlation import gettext_lazy as _

class Country(models.Model):
    # your fields
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Country / State")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Countries / States")
```

Comment: I avoided this kind of approach guessing that model's verbose_name was used somewhere else than in admin's menu. But I'll use it while I don't have a better solution. The ideal solution is ModelAdmin having a `verbose_name` override, like TabularInline does.
Thanks for you answer...

Comment: I think this kind of solution doesn't exist, but you can report a feature in django site :)