# Django Admin. Change the title of app page

Tags: django, django-admin

The default title for every app page is:

`verbose_name + "administration"`

How can I change it?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19638864

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently Django does not provide a clean way to override this header text, because it is hardcoded in the `django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.app_index` method.

However, if you really need to do it, you can override this method and replace the default header with your text.

You will need to use your own custom AdminSite, if you're not using it yet. So, you'll need to change your `urls.py` to point to your custom class instead of default django admin urls, and also you'll need to register your models in your class, instead of default site.

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

```
def app_index(self, request, app_label, extra_context=None):
    response: TemplateResponse = super().app_index(request, app_label, extra_context)
    response.context_data['title'] = 'Your header goes here;
    return response
```

Be sure to check the original method code, because it may differ in different Django versions. This code provided above is for Django 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using, in your `admin.py`:

```
admin.site.site_title = "My DEBUG Panel"
```

or similarly for header like in `admin.py` or in `settings.py`:

```
ADMIN_SITE_HEADER = "My DEBUG Panel"
```

Comment: It does not answer the question, because it is about App administration page, not about index page

Answer (score 0):

As [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9122641/pavel-shishmarev) notes, it's complicated to override the header text because it is hardcoded.

However, it is easy to work around this with javascript.

First, add the following to `templates/admin/base_site.html`:

```
{% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1 id='adminTitle'>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

Notice the `id='adminTitle'` in the H1 tag.

Then, add javascript between the `</h1>` and the `{% endif %}` resulting in:

```
{% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1 id='adminTitle'>{{ title }}</h1><script>

if (adminTitle.innerHTML == 'MyApp administration')
  adminTitle.innerHTML = 'My New Title'

</script>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

Obviously you can write more complex javascript to replace parts of the title.